# What is the oxygen concentration in the lumen of the small intestine?

Tags: human-biology

I am researching how oxygen affects enzyme activity in the small intestine, and I need to know how much oxygen there is in the lumen. I understand that the average amount of O2 in the lumen is ~2% (<10 mmHg), however I am curious as to how the number changes from the beginning of the small intestine to the end. If you were to measure O2 concentration from the beginning to end, would it be a decreasing linear or exponential curve.

Answer (score 1):

From a [recent review by Konjar *et al.* (2021)](https://www.mdpi.com/1422-0067/22/17/9170), see Figure 2 and associated text:

> **There is also a steep decrease in oxygen longitudinally from the small intestine towards the colon.**

> Longitudinally—from the small intestine to the colon—the oxygen level
> drops (Figure 2) [15,16], and a negative gradient is also observed
> from lamina propria towards the lumen. To illustrate this, in mice,
> pO2 drops from 58 mmHg in the stomach to 32 mmHg in the duodenum,
> through 11 mmHg in the ascending column and to 3 mmHg in the sigmoid
> column (all values measured using electron paramagnetic resonance,
> EPR) [16].

For your convenience, I link references [15](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4615-0075-9_12) and [16](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC16376/), respectively.

Comment: Although this is helpful, the values are taken from experiments done on mice. I am interested in the human small intestine.